# how to enable an item for purchase in quickbooks

Tags: c#, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to add bill in quickbooks i can able to add it  in "Itemize by account" and it is visible to me but for "Itemize by Product/Service" i can able to add item but the items are not visible in the dropdown by default. If I chose any item it is asking like "Do you want to mark the item 'Sales' for purchases?" if I press yes a popup window is opening in that if I enable the checkbox ("Purchasing Information")  and then pressed save button the item is getting displayed. I am inserting those items using c#. How to enable that checkbox using quickbook library classes or how to display those items in the "Itemize by Product/Service" dropdowns using c#.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Code:

```
{
 string accessToken = "lvprdRM1HLr6o11Bnim1gRezlXWbFfADnS1Btvm2L4VPOTRI";
            string appToken = "2sdfsdfsdf345DSF4dAS3afasd34192cd";
            string accessTokenSecret = "JfQTrprW83JTWhSVHD3uf7th53gP0SOzBQcn4Nrt";
            string consumerKey = "qyprdMSG42SDF4dtQZTiKVc28dywR";
            string consumerSecret = "JPfXE17Ynasdasd56sSAwvuXkF2M71lbDb7blhcLB7HeF";
            string companyID = "812947021";
            OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessTokenSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
            ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(oauthValidator, appToken, companyID, IntuitServicesType.QBO);
            DataServices service = new DataServices(context);
            Item oItem = new Item();
            oItem.Name = "Test Product One";
            oItem.Type = ItemTypeEnum.Product;
            oItem.TypeSpecified = true;

            oItem.PrefVendorRef.VendorId = new IdType { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "42" };
           oItem.PrefVendorRef.VendorName = "CWR";
            oItem.ExpenseAccountRef.AccountName = "Accounts Receivable (A/R)";
            oItem.ExpenseAccountRef.AccountId = new IdType { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value="8"};
            oItem.IncomeAccountRef.AccountId = new IdType { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = "31" };
            oItem.IncomeAccountRef.AccountName = "Cost of Goods Sold";
            oItem.PurchaseCost = new Money() { Amount = 12.02M, AmountSpecified = true };
            oItem.QtyOnPurchaseOrder = 10m;
            oItem.QtyOnPurchaseOrderSpecified = true;
            oItem.QtyOnSalesOrder = 10m;
            oItem.QtyOnSalesOrderSpecified = true;
            var itemRespVal = service.Add(oItem);
            string id = itemRespVal.Id.Value;
            string syncToken = itemRespVal.SyncToken;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a Plus subscription or an Essential subscription?

Comment: yes I have Plus subscription